# Shade entire page, unshade selected elements on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-tools

I'm trying to make a page inspection tool, where:

- The whole page is shaded
- Hovered elements are unshaded.

Unlike a lightbox type app (which is similar), the hovered items should remain in place and (ideally) not be duplicated.

Originally, looking at the image lightbox implementations, I thought of appending an overlay to the document, then raising the z-index of elements upon hover. However this technique does not work in this case, as the overlay blocks additional mouse hovers:

```
$(function() {
    window.alert('started');
    $('<div id="overlay" />').hide().appendTo('body').fadeIn('slow');


    $("p").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).css( {"z-index":5} );
        }, 
        function () {
            $(this).css( {"z-index":0} );
        }
    );
```

Alternatively, JQueryTools has an 'expose' and 'mask' tool, which I have tried with the code below:

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
         alert("Hello world!");
    });

    // Mask whole page
    $(document).mask("#222");

    // Mask and expose on however / unhover 
    $("p").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).expose();
        }, 
        function () {
            $(this).mask();
        }
    );

});
```

Hovering does not work unless I disable the initial page masking. Any thoughts of how best to achieve this, with plain JQuery, JQuery tools expose, or some other technique? Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is make a copy of the element and insert it back into the DOM outside of your overlay (with a higher z-index). You'll need to calculate its position to do so, but that's not too difficult.

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ByEt5/5/).

In writing this I re-learned the fact that something with zero opacity cannot trigger an event. Therefore you can't use .fade(), you have to specifically set the opacity to a non-zero but very small number.

```
$(document).ready(function() { init() })

function init() {
    $('.overlay').show()
    $('.available').each(function() {
       var newDiv = $('<div>').appendTo('body');
       var myPos = $(this).position()  
       newDiv.addClass('available')
       newDiv.addClass('peek')
       newDiv.addClass('demoBorder')                
       newDiv.css('top',myPos.top+'px')
       newDiv.css('left',myPos.left+'px')
       newDiv.css('height',$(this).height()+'px')
       newDiv.css('width',$(this).width()+'px')  
       newDiv.hover(function()
          {newDiv.addClass('full');newDiv.stop();newDiv.fadeTo('fast',.9)},function()
          {newDiv.removeClass('full');newDiv.fadeTo('fast',.1)})   
    })  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I hover over the element if the overlay is blocking the selection?

Comment: When you load the page, find all of the elements eligible for the effect. Make an empty DIV on top of the overlay at the same position with the same dimensions. Hook up an event to these that will reveal the contents.

Comment: Yup. Put a border on them to test so you can tell where they are.

Comment: I guess what I don't quite understand is how the top-layer div - the one which will catch hover events - can attach those events to the corresponding bottom-level layer. Does there have to be a 1:1 copy of each bottom-level element on top of the overlay? Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Here, I thought I'd actually build it, just for fun. http://jsfiddle.net/ByEt5/1/

Comment: Thanks, the code makes it a lo more understandable. Want to pop it in your answer so others can see it in future? Then I will reward you with delicious karma, good Sir.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the prototype syntax, but this might give you a good idea.

```
function overlay() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setStyle({
    position: "absolute",
    left: "0px",
    right: "0px",
    top: "0px",
    bottom: "0px",
    backgroundColor: "#000000",
    opacity: "0.2",
    zIndex: "20"
  })
  div.setAttribute('id','over');
  $('body').insert(div);
}

$(document).observe('mousemove', function(e) {
  var left = e.clientX,
      top = e.clientY,
      ele = document.elementFromPoint(left,top);
      //from here you can create that empty div and insert this element in there
})

overlay();
```

Comment: Thanks. The overlay part is obvious, but could you explain the rest? What makes the mouse movement be detected as affecting the element, rather than the overlay?