# Dim page except for panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page with multiple panels on it. When a user clicks on a button one panel becomes invisible and another becomes visible. I was wondering if it is possible to dim the entire page except for the panel that has just become visible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683323/shade-entire-page-unshade-selected-elements-on-hover

Comment: Is there a way to do this using code behind, not jquery?

Comment: i dont think so, but you can do is to create a masking div, initially hide it and from code behind, using Client.RegisterStartUpScript show it to mask the entire page

Comment: that sounds doable, what about the panel that needs to be not dimmed though?

Comment: @mattgcon, you have to adjust z-indices of div elements - for example, masking div should have higher z-index that page elements and then visible div should have z-index even higher than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asp.net panels will be rendered as

```
<div>
```

in the html, so why not write some javascript which which sets these to hidden? You could give them a class which you use to identify what to hide e.g.

```
<div class="container">
```

and then hide all the divs based on that. As Tim B James suggests, JQuery is great for doing this kind of thing, and can give you animations, fading, delays etc, which are really easy to get started with.

If you'd rather do it in the code-behind, you could loop through all the panels, finding and hiding them programmatically. Then show the correct one. This solution might be best if you have complex validation or something needed for the panel contents.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid to dip into some jQuery, then I would take a look at the jQuery Tools Exposure feature. Found here http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/toolbox/expose/index.html

If you view the demo, this might be what you are looking to achieve. It is also very easy to set up, with minimal coding.